# Understanding a limit to infinity as an integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

So I'm given the task of finding this limit when viewing Infinite Sequences (so $n\in \mathbb{N})$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{0}n]{e}+\sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{0}n]{e^2}+\ldots+\sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{0}n]{e^{2n}}}{n}$$

I looked up the answer and it says that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{0}n]{e}+\sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{0}n]{e^2}+\ldots+\sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{0}n]{e^{2n}}}{n}
=
\int_{0}^{2} e^x dx
$$

After this it's easy to get $e^2 - 1$. But I do not understand why the equality is true. If you could help me out with a hint or a bit more that would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Cauchy / Riemann / Darboux sum and $e^x$ is increasing.

Comment: Denote your limit in question by $l$. Finite geometric series gives

$$
S_n=\sum_{k= 1}^{2n}e^{k/n}=(e^2-1)\frac{e^{1/n}}{e^{1/n}-1}
$$

Therefore $S_n\sim n(e^2-1)+O(1)$ since $e^{1/n}\sim1+\frac{1}n+O(n^{-2})$ or

>$$
l=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{S_n}{n}=e^2-1=\int_0^2e^x
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the integral to the sum [in this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cyyxum8ocg) to see how a Riemann sum works.  Play with it and see what happens as $n\to\infty$.

At $n=10$, we have

[image]

Comment: Ok so this helped a ton to understand.

Comment: @D.Brito Glad to help.  As a last note, letting $n\to-\infty$ in the graph is the "right Riemann sum", whereas $n\to+\infty$ represents the "left Riemann sum".

Comment: Oh yeah, I got that right away. Great interactive piece.